# Is there something wrong with the file path?

Tags: css, url

[image]The `background-url()` function was used to apply the background screen to `PurpleCloud.png`. However, no matter what I do, the image is not applied. Where did we go wrong?

After learning about how to write a file path, I tried several methods, but there was no change. How should I write it?

Comment: Did you mean to use something like `background-image: url("../../media/examples/lizard.png");`? That example was taken from the MDN documentation at [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved **in text form**

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be something like:

```
background-image: url('assets/PurpleCloud.png');
```

In your case, if you use background image on a div, make sure you also add width and height to that div, try inspecting using Chrome devTool it will show you the element and its css.

Comment: I edit, But no change. I attached an image.

Comment: I think the correct path should be "../../assets/images/PurpleCloud.png"

Answer (score 1):

Try background-image: url('/src/assets/PurpleCloud.png');

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-image: url('src/assets/images/PurpleCloud.png');
```

or

```
background-image: url('../../assets/images/PurpleCloud.png');
```

Both are correct but second one has related path.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.